# Getting the date for each day within a date range in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I'm looking for a way to get a list of instances a certain day appears between two date periods in SQL.

I have a range:

```
DECLARE @ViewStartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ViewEndDate DATETIME

SET @ViewStartDate = '2014-09-08 00:00:00.000';
SET @ViewEndDate = '2014-09-30 00:00:00.000';
```

And need to get e.g. every Monday (date) within that list. I have tried looking all over for an answer as specific as this and can't seem to find anything relevant.

The reason is that it will be used in a logistics program to calculate delivery dates between a date range where the required delivery day is every Monday.

Comment: Search on 'Tally Table'. Do you have to consider public holidays? in that case search on 'Calendar Table'. Post back if you want more info

Comment: I believe public holidays are not important at this time. I will look up tally table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query.
The first part in the cte is to find the next monday after the startdate. Then keep adding one week until the end date.

```
;WITH Dates([Date])
AS
(
    --If the start date is sunday or monday
    SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@ViewStartDate) <=2
        --Then the monday of that week 
        THEN DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 1, @ViewStartDate), 0) 
    ELSE 
         -- Mondy of the next week
         DATEADD(WEEK,1,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ViewStartDate), 0))
    END
    UNION ALL

    -- Loop by joining the CTE Dates, until the date < @ViewEndDate
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, 1,Date)  
    FROM Dates
    WHERE DATEADD(WEEK, 1,Date) <= @ViewEndDate
)
SELECT [Date] 
FROM Dates;
```

Comment: What if the start date isn't a Sunday or a Monday?

Comment: Then the coming moday is taken as the start for the output.